# Comment or uncomment js block using gruntjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

How to automate comment or uncomment certain block of code in .js files using gruntjs? The reason for this is there are things I wrote just for frontend development purpose (i.e. sending fake data / events). But when going to deployment, I want to make sure these code are commented out and the real ajax event code are uncommented.

Let me know if there is workaround. Or whether I have to write my own gruntjs for this. Thanks

Comment: If you're using uglify there is a `perserveComments` flag

Comment: I would personally be really uncomfortable automating test/production code changes via grunt.  You may want to instead consider reworking your code a bit to make it more testable.  In other words, test the code that will be going to production outside of the production code itself.

Comment: @megawac it seems like `perserveComments` only touches the comments, no? What about "making" the comment in existing line of code? @MichaelMilom, you are right & it's ugly hack. I guess I need better practice on mocking ajax data in dev vs. prod environment. Suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into this last night for a personal project and found that [`grunt-template`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/grunt-template) suits this bill quite nicely. You can wrap code in commented out lo-dash/underscore like template blocks and it will be evaluated during the grunt compile.

The way I'm using this in my project is as follows:

```
// ....
//concat files for package

template: {
    build: {
        options: {
            data: grunt.file.readJSON('./package.json')
        },
        files: {
            'js/dist/package-<%= pkg.version %>.js': ['js/dist/package-<%= pkg.version %>.js']
        }
    }
}
// ....


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-template');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'concat',
    'template',
    'uglify',
]);
```

Then somewhere in `js/dist/package-<%= pkg.version %>.js` if I have a line like

```
// <% if(development) { %>
console.log("better remove this line Johnny");
alert("or the clients will be pissed");
// <% } %>
```

Grunt will evaluate package.development to determine whether to include this line or not. Pretty neat - I'm using it to exclude unnessary code that may not be supported by the client's server. Another great thing is the javascript code will still have valid syntax and run without the compile

Comment: Where is the `development` variable coming from in this `<% if(development) { %>`?

Comment: `development` would be set in `package.json` in my example --- it just needs to be set in `options.data` in the `template` setup

Comment: So in package.json, I will just have `"development": true` as one of the key/value?

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Michael; I highly recommended extracting your test code into tests, that way it never gets deleted and if you need to refactor, will help you there too. [Mockjax](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax) is especially designed for this, and you can pair it with something like QUnit as in this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/NickJosevski/1564578

Comment: Using Mockjax works if I don't do build like 10 times a day (due super agile process). Using Mockjax, I still have to go into the code and pull out `$.mockjax` each time by hand. Actually it's more clumsy than just doing normal ajax call but point url into a static .JSON file.

Comment: I meant to *extract* your test code, i.e. move it out into a file solely for testing that doesn't get included in the production JS. It may be beyond the scope of the question but you'd probably have an easier time of it with using an AMD loader. Swap out config depending on your environment; i.e. have a class for AJAX calls that could be replaced with a mock one depending on a value in the AMD config.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the idea suggested is to build an abstracted class that somehow route to either real or fake ajax calls. Right?

Comment: Exactly. So that you can use test code as and when you need to.